# Escape single quote in cell content in a QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

## My Problem

I have [a Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R0u3WJNhzycc4ZGvU7jkqoOd57OfgR0b7t1boi1vrXU/edit#gid=0) with two tabs - one containing regexes and values:

[image: Regex sheet]

And the other containing phrases which matches regex in the first tab, and a `QUERY` Formula that picks the right value from the regex column for each matching phrase:

```
=QUERY(Regex!A:B, "SELECT B WHERE lower('"&A1&"') CONTAINS A LIMIT 1")
```

[image: Data with failed query]

For example, `Winter in California` and `Summer in californiaaaaa` both match '.*california.*', and matched with the `Sunny` phrase.

The problem is that if the matched cell contains a single quote, it breaks the parsing of the query.

For unrelated reasons, I can't add columns to the table - it is being downloaded as a CSV by an external service and its format can't be changed.

## What Have I Tried

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) between the `&&` that replaces the single quote with an empty string
- Reviewing [the manual](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select)
- Using CONTAINS, which suffer from the same quoting problem

## My Question

**How can I escape single quotes in a cell content in the concat operator (&), in a query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- that's a common issue which can be outsmarted like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(Regex!A:B, "'", "♦"), 
   "select Col2 
    where lower('"&SUBSTITUTE(A1, "'", "♦")&"') contains Col1 
    limit 1"))
  ```

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(Regex!A:B, "'", "♦"), 
   "select Col2 
    where lower('"&SUBSTITUTE(A1, "'", "♦")&"') contains Col1 
    limit 1"), "♦", "'"))
  ```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 5):

Plain simple quote "inversion":

```
=query('Book list'!A:F,"select B,C,D,E where F=""free"" and D="""&E1&"""")
```